# How do I keep Windows XP computers from turning Master Browser elections back on?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, wired-networking

I have a wired LAN network that includes two XP computers and a Windows 7 computer. I previously turned off the two XP computers from running in the [master browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Master_Browser) elections so the Windows 7 computer would automatically be the master browser (in the hopes of solving other networking issues I am having). I did that by running `services.msc` on the XP computers and disabling the Computer Browser service.

I turn the Windows 7 computer off every night but the Windows XP computers take an extremely long time to turn on because they are old and not very good, so I leave them on. When I checked the Master Browser status today, both of the Windows XP computers were set to Master Browser and the Windows 7 computer wasn't, which means that the Windows XP computers turned back on running in the master browser elections by enabling the computer browser service.

Is there some way I can stop them from doing this without leaving the Windows 7 computer on indefinitely?

Comment: Please explain what "Master Browser" elections are exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Master_Browser

Comment: How did you turn off the elections in your previous attempts?

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: AT Ramhound. Instead of asking them to tell you what a term means, can't you google a term and state that you have but that you still don't understand, and what it is that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

In registry key:

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services \Browser\Parameters

with this you can make one computer as a master browser and prevent the others from becoming master browser with
IsDomainMaster="FALSE"
MaintainServerlist="FALSE"

and make the machine you choose to become Master Browser with

IsDomainMaster="TRUE"
MaintainServerlist="TRUE"